# Kendo UI MVC Grid, column-cell subtracted with the previous column-cell

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a child-grid where I want to to subtract the 'Value' column-cell with the previous 'Value' column-cell client-side, I tried using a ClientTemplate but I couldn't get it to work and it doesn't seem like Telerik has anything documented around this.

**Ex**, 
Let's say I am looking at the 'Value' with the 'SensorId' 3, I want the 'Change' column to be: 'Value' where 'SensorId' == 3 **subtract** 'Value' where 'SensorId' == 4, and so forth.

```
@(
Html.Kendo().Grid<ErvinBeta.Models.ViewModels.ValueViewModel>().Name("ValueGrid#=SensorId#")
    .DataSource(ds => ds.Ajax()
    .Model(m => m.Id(sv => sv.SensorId))
    .PageSize(15)
    .Read(read => read.Action("ReadValue", "Home", new { SensorId = "#=SensorId#" }))
    .Sort(sort => sort.Add(sv => sv.Timestamp).Descending()))

    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(sensorValue => sensorValue.ValueId).Visible(false);
        columns.Bound(sensorValue => sensorValue.SensorId).Visible(false);
        columns.Bound(sensorValue => sensorValue.Value).Title("Value").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "valueColumn" }).Width(150).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains")).Cell(cell => cell.ShowOperators(false)));
        columns.Bound(sensorValue => sensorValue.Category.Unit).Title("Unit").Width(200).Filterable(false);
        columns.Bound(sensorValue => sensorValue.Timestamp).Title("Timestamp").Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains")).Cell(cell => cell.ShowOperators(false)));
    })
    .Scrollable()
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 600px;", @class="valueTable"})
    .ToClientTemplate()
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i guess this functionality you cannot achieve with any client libraries such as `kendo`. You could create another column and compute their values at server, and then provide the grid data to web/client

Comment: Seems like that's probably the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to sort it out, **outside of Kendo however**.

I added my columns to a list inside of my controller, sorted it by timestamp and looped through it.

```
public ActionResult ReadValue([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, int sensorId){

        using (var db = new Entity())
        {
            var sensorValues = db.SensorValue.Where(sv => sv.SensorId == sensorId)
                .Select(select => new ValueViewModel
                {
                    ValueId = select.Id,
                    SensorId = select.SensorId,
                    Value = select.Value,
                    Comment = select.Comment,
                    Timestamp = select.Timestamp,
                    Category = new CategoryViewModel()
                    {
                        CategoryId = select.ValueCategory.Id,
                        CategoryName = select.ValueCategory.Name,
                        Unit = select.ValueCategory.Unit
                    },
                    EntryTimestamp = select.EntryTimestamp
                }).OrderBy(order => order.Timestamp).ToList();
            for(int i=0; i< sensorValues.Count;i++)
            {
                if(i>0)
                {
                    sensorValues[i].ChangedValue = sensorValues[i].Value - sensorValues[i - 1].Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    sensorValues[i].ChangedValue = 0;
                }
            }
            return Json(sensorValues.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
    }
```